# How do you make the font size of Squarify label proportionate to the size of the square?

Tags: python, visualization, treemap, squarify

I'm trying to make a treemap with squarify with some squares much bigger than the others.

| title | counts | labels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | A - 100 |
| B | 30 | B - 30 |
| C | 25 | C - 25 |
| D | 2 | D - 2 |
| E | 2 | E - 2 |
| F | 2 | F - 2 |
| G | 2 | G - 2 |

```
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (12,12))
        ax = squarify.plot(sizes=df['counts'], 
                           label=df['labels'],
                           alpha=0.5)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
```

Is there a way to make the font size of A as big as its square size, font B smaller than A, font C a bit smaller than B, and the rest very small?

I found a parameter:

```
text_kwargs={'fontsize':10}
```

But it doesn't allow me to insert a list of sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275079/auto-fitting-text-into-boxes-in-matplotlib) can give you some hints to solve your problem.

Recently I have created a [matplotlib-extra](https://github.com/chenyulue/matplotlib-extra) project, which includes some extra functions to matplotlib. Currently it has a `treemap` and an `AutoFitText` class. The `treemap` supports the hierarchical treemap.

For your case, it will be simple:

```py
import mpl_extra.treemap as tr
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'title':list('ABCDEFG'), 
                   'counts':[100, 30, 25, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
df['labels'] = [f'{a} - {b}' for a,b in zip(df['title'], df['counts'])]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7), dpi=100, subplot_kw=dict(aspect=1.156))

tr.treemap(ax, df, area='counts', labels='labels', 
           cmap='Set2', fill='title',
           rectprops=dict(ec='w'),
           textprops=dict(c='w'))

ax.axis('off')
```

It gives the following treemap:

[image]